# Converting an array of shorts to an array of doubles

Tags: c++, c, arrays, types

How I could convert array of type short to array of type double in C/C++?

I have code to read audio data from wav file and output is array of type short. So now I want to use this data for FFT (I don't want use libraries).

Any tricks or ideas?

Comment: Why can't a simple loop do? Or are you asking for a more efficient solution using SSE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't *convert* the array; you can however create a new array with the converted values:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

short src[10] = ...;

double dst[sizeof(src)/sizeof(short)];

std::copy(std::begin(src), std::end(src), dst);  // generic, C++11
std::copy(src, src + 10, dst);                   // a bit more hackish
```

Even better would be to use `std::array<float, 10> src;` etc.

If your "arrays" are really dynamic data structures, it becomes even easier:

```
std::vector<float> src = ... ;
std::vector<double> dst(src.begin(), src.end());
```

Comment: More than likely he wants it it normalized to the range -1.0 to 1.0 as is standard in audio. His input is likely unsigned, thus he needs to `(src - 32K)/32K` for each element.

Comment: Prefer `sizeof(src)/sizeof(src[0])` over `sizeof(src)/sizeof(short)`. Just in case in the future you change the type of src.