# Convert short array to float on Android+NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to implement something simple as a test using C++ on Android and record.read().

I'm passing a short array to my C++ function, but it's necessary to convert this array to a float array in order to use a C++ library. I can just manually initialize a float array with the values but I'm implying this would be a horrible bottleneck on an Android app.

Right now the only efficient solution is to directly use float[] as the buffer for record.read() (which requires API 23), but maybe there's another possibility.

Is there any efficient way to do this on Android or any alternative?

Comment: How big is the array, that you assume it will be a bottleneck when copying to new array in c?

Comment: Live audio samples. Solved with `std::copy` thanks to this C++ answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8619071/1208656.

Comment: And how do you think std::copy works?

Comment: In a more optimized way (compiler wise) than using a for myself on NDK. I'm guessing the "hacky" method in there use memory pointers, so it's actually interesting.